# POCO C++ Encryption / Decryption

Tags: c++, rsa, poco-libraries

I am working with the POCO C++ API and using the CRYPTO module for encryption and decryption. I am having an issue with decryption not working and retuning the following error:

```
   RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error; error:04065072:rsa 
   routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed"
```

I am using an RSA key/pair. The generation of the Key pair

```
void Support::GenerateKeyPair(std::string& PublicKey, std::string& PrivateKey)
{   
    Poco::Crypto::RSAKey key(Poco::Crypto::RSAKey::KL_1024, Poco::Crypto::RSAKey::EXP_SMALL);

    std::ostringstream strPub;
    std::ostringstream strPriv;

    key.save(&strPub, &strPriv); // EmailEncryptionPassphrase);
    PublicKey = strPub.str();
    PrivateKey = strPriv.str();             
}
```

These keys are placed within a file - and will be explicitly retrieved as strings for encryption/decryption activity -- i.e. encryption/decryption in not using the file directly

My encryption operation is the following:

```
    std::istringstream iPub(PublicKey);
    Poco::Crypto::RSAKey MulaRSAKey(&iPub);

    Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory& factory = Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::defaultFactory();
    Poco::Crypto::Cipher* MulaCipherImpl = factory.createCipher(MulaRSAKey);


    //encrypt using RSA (keys prepped with RSA)
    EncryptedData = MulaCipherImpl->encryptString(Data, Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Encoding::ENC_NONE);
```

And again -- the public key is a string that is retrieved from a configuration file. This operation does not fail - encryption appears to be working.

I decrypt the data like the following:

```
   std::istringstream iPub(Keys.PublicKey);
   std::istringstream iPriv(Keys.PrivateKey);
   Poco::Crypto::RSAKey MulaRSAKey(&iPub, &iPriv); // EmailEncryptionPassphrase);
   Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory& factory = Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::defaultFactory();
   Poco::Crypto::Cipher* MulaCipherImpl = factory.createCipher(MulaRSAKey);

   DecryptedData = std::make_shared<std::string>(MulaCipherImpl->decryptString(EncryptData, 
         Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Encoding::ENC_NONE));
```

This is where the failure is occuring. The decryption is failing with the padding error I mentioned above. The decryption operation also uses strings for the key pair from the configuration file.

I was unsure if the key pair was valid so I used a RSA Key (online) tester to validate the key pair - and the test was able to encrypt and decrypt. So looks like the key is valid.

I was able to change the encoding from  Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Encoding::ENC_NONE to Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Encoding::ENC_BINHEX and decryption did pass -- generated a hex output - but did pass. The confusing aspect of this is that the encryption operation was still using the Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Encoding::ENC_NONE. My understanding was that encrypt and decrypt should be using the same encoding. This though does not clarify why the NONE based encoding is failing on decryption.

If anyone could clarify what is configured incorrectly - would be a great help.

thx
Peter

Comment: why are you making a shared pointer to a std::string ? it's effectively shared pointer to char* buffer anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

OK -- question is mute. Realized that the encrypted data (to unencrypt) was invalid. Got modified within JSON operations used to migrate the data to remote servers.

Peter

Comment: As the problem was resolved in a way that probably won't help future readers, you may want to delete it.